# How to have one DB URI for read and one for read-write

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have an application that is running on AWS and I have a Database on Amazon RDS.
I have created a read-replica of the database and I have used HAProxy for load balancing the database.
The problem is that using the HAProxy load balancing URL my `writes` are failing half the time.

I need to have two `SQLALCHEMY URI` in my database connection to RDS and tell my app that "use this connection for reading and use the other one for write."

I am asking this question in a different language for the second time. [My first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283298/read-read-write-uris-for-amazon-web-services-rds) didn't get any answers.

**Update:** While searching I found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947918/read-slave-read-write-master-setup), but I have to use transactions with these connections and the answers there are not helpful in my scenario.

Comment: @PaulBecotte Thanks. But answers there aren't applicable to my case. The person has mentioned that it won't work in case of transactions.

Comment: Um, yeah... you can't open a transaction on one database and close it on another. If you need to do a "read-update-write" cycle, that needs to be on the "write" connection. Even if you want to do the read from the replica, you should still do a "select with for update" on the master when opening that transaction. (also, that is the author of sqlalchemy)